# How to align text to the left of a right-aligned headline?

Tags: css, text-align

I have a headline aligned to the right of a site and a left-aligned text block below, which should be aligned to the beginning of the headline.

I'm having difficulties finding a CSS solution without using width for the text block, because it doesn't apply to different headline widths.

```css
div {
  float: right;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.textblock {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>headlinelong</h1>
  <div class="textblock">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/hpmacher/pen/bXLmGL

I expect the text block to always have the same width as the headline, regardless of how long the headline is. But right now it is controlled with width and therefore doesn't change.

Comment: I appreciate your interest on HTML, but also learn the HTML standards where and how to use the appropriate HTML elements in the application please.
When your trying to display paragraph text always go with <p> tag instead of Div. <div > has specific purpose to used in the template.

Comment: CSS position is the best method to achieve this requirement.
Wrap the both heading and text and go with the CSS position.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:
>
> ```
> .textblock {
>     font-size: 16px;
>     width: 500px;
>     float: left;
>     text-align: left;
> }
> ```

Edit:

If you are ok with using JS you can apply this simple script after `</body>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var headline = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
    var textblock = document.getElementsByClassName('textblock')[0];

    textblock.style.width = headline.clientWidth + 'px';
    textblock.style.textAlign = 'left';
</script>
```

I suggest modifying css

> ```
> div {
>     float: right;
> }
> h1 {
>     font-size: 60px;
>     margin: 0;
>     letter-spacing: 4px;
>     float:right;
> }
> .textblock {
>     font-size: 16px;
>     clear: both;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. It does set the text block to the left and aligns it with headline, but it still has a specific width. The text block should be as width as the headline.

Comment: You can checkout this pen: https://codepen.io/edekk/pen/rXJQmj

I've added an observer to keep track of changes in h1 element styles. You can change font-size property of that element and it will call a function responsible for setting the width to a .textblock div

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as follows, explanatory comments in the code below:

```css
body>div {
  /* Using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining named grid areas; because you were
     originally floating right, I assume you want
     space to the left, hence the empty areas
     (marked with a period ('.'): */
  grid-template-areas: ". header" ". content";
  /* defining the column widths; here the first column is measured
     as one fractional unit (1fr) of the available space remaining
     after the second column has been assigned the minimum width
     (min-content) required to contain the content: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  /* aligning text to the right: */
  text-align: right;
  /* placing the <h1> in the named 'header' area: */
  grid-area: header;
}

.textblock {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  /* placing the content in the named 'content'
     area: */
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>headlinelong</h1>
  <div class="textblock">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata</p>
    <p>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
      Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above does run into problems in the event of white-space in the `<h1>` element; one option to resolve that problem is to use `max-content` in place of `min-content`, giving:

```
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
```

```css
body > div {
  /* Using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining named grid areas; because you were
     originally floating right, I assume you want
     space to the left, hence the empty areas
     (marked with a period ('.'): */
  grid-template-areas:
    ". header"
    ". content";
  /* defining the column widths; here the first column is measured
     as one fractional unit (1fr) of the available space remaining
     after the second column has been assigned the maximum width
     (max-content) required to contain the content: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  /* aligning text to the right: */
  text-align: right;
  /* placing the <h1> in the named 'header' area: */
  grid-area: header;
}

.textblock {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  /* placing the content in the named 'content'
     area: */
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>headline long</h1>
  <div class="textblock"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata</p>
    <p>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
      Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
</div>
```

Or, alternatively, specifying:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in the rules for the `<h1>` element:

```css
body > div {
  /* Using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining named grid areas; because you were
     originally floating right, I assume you want
     space to the left, hence the empty areas
     (marked with a period ('.'): */
  grid-template-areas:
    ". header"
    ". content";
  /* defining the column widths; here the first column is measured
     as one fractional unit (1fr) of the available space remaining
     after the second column has been assigned the minimum width
     (min-content) required to contain the content: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  /* aligning text to the right: */
  text-align: right;
  /* placing the <h1> in the named 'header' area: */
  grid-area: header;
  /* preventing the content of the <h1> from wrapping to
     a new line (with long content this can itself cause
     more problems as content either overflows the screen
     requiring scrolling, or becomes inaccessible due to
     overflow handling: */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.textblock {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  /* placing the content in the named 'content'
     area: */
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>headline long</h1>
  <div class="textblock"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata</p>
    <p>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
      Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
</div>
```

Though the easiest solution, given that in most cases the `<h1>` is likely to be the longest content, and the start of the `div.textblock` will always be aligned with the beginning of the `<h1>` anyway, to simply use the default `text-align: left` on the `<h1>` element:

```css
body > div {
  /* Using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining named grid areas; because you were
     originally floating right, I assume you want
     space to the left, hence the empty areas
     (marked with a period ('.'): */
  grid-template-areas:
    ". header"
    ". content";
  /* defining the column widths; here the first column is measured
     as one fractional unit (1fr) of the available space remaining
     after the second column has been assigned the minimum width
     (min-content) required to contain the content: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  /* placing the <h1> in the named 'header' area: */
  grid-area: header;
}

.textblock {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  /* placing the content in the named 'content'
     area: */
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>headline long</h1>
  <div class="textblock"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata</p>
    <p>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
      Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
</div>
```

References:

- [Fractional unit (`fr`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-flex-fr).
- [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).
- [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
- [`max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content).
- [`min-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#min-content).
- [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The simple and great solution with CSS

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 120px;
  margin: 0;
}
.textblock {
    font-size: 16px;
    position:absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: calc(100% + 15px);
}
.wrap{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.article{
  position: relative; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="article">
    <h1>headlinelong 1</h1>
     <div class="textblock">
       This text block should be always as width as the headline. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you could find the solution here